# Prove that $\mathcal{P}(A) \sim \{0,1\}^A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that $\mathcal{P}(A) \sim \{0,1\}^A$

We might can find a bijection function, however I am trying to prove it in other way.
I want to F, G 1-1 functions and prove that those functions are inverse each other, once I did it, we know from a another proved claim that function is inverse if and only if function is bijection.

I define $F:\mathcal{P}(A) \to {0,1}^A$ by the following rule, for all $X\in \mathcal{P}(A)$, we have function $F(X): A \to \{0,1\}$ and for all $a\in A$ we define function $F(X)(a)=0$ its easy to prove that this function is 1-1.

Now I have to define $G:\{0,1\}^A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$ by the rule: for all $f\in \{0,1\}$, $G(f)=?$

My question is how can we define $G(f)$ to be 1-1 function?
Moreover, any suggestions on this strategy will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If your $F$ maps every $X$ to the map $a\mapsto 0$, then this is certainly not injective once $A$ is nontrivial

Comment: $G(f)=f^(-1)(1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $X\subseteq A$, define the characteristic function
$\chi_X:A\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ such that $\chi_X(a)=1$ iff $a\in X$.
This gives the bijection $P(A)\rightarrow\{0,1\}^A:X\mapsto \chi_X$.